Is This an Irregular Triangle? What Is Its Generating Function?
I found this triangle out of curiosity in the image.

How did I make it? It was very simple. term_Left_above + 2 * term_Right_above
Bordered by 1 es, of course.
If I had to guess the O.G.F. $$ (1-x) / (x^2-x-2) $$
This triangle is known to OEIS. A112857 BTW
Although, how such a simple thing produces: "number of Green's R-classes in the semigroup of order-preserving partial transformations". I have no idea, what that is - at all.

Random relevant paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04941

Okay, great paper, but nothing of an Irregular Triangle. If that is "what this is" as I asked. () Otherwise, it shows a relationship to Turing machines and tape-based automatons. () No mention of Generating function - either.

The OEIS entry gives the O.G.F. of $$\frac{1-2x}{(1-x)(1-2x-xy)}$$(A double-index sequence is going to have a two-variable generating function.) It also gives the formula $$T(n,k) = \sum_{j = k}^n \binom n j \binom {j-1}{k-1}$$

Thank you @PaulSinclair
